# Excel, How could show full note when frozen some heading rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

[image]

As you can see in this picture, I froze 4 rows in this excel sheet, and now I can see the full note of one grid, part of the note is swallowed by the none fixed rows marked by red rectangle.

So how can I stay rows are frozen and also can I see the full note?

Comment: What do you mean by Full Note !!

Comment: as you can see in the red rectangle, part of the note is swallowed by the none fixed rows.